# laravel uploading HTTP ERROR 500 after editing index.php

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

My PHP version is 7.2
i have uploaded my my laravel 5.7.9 in to public_html folder and then i moved files of public folder into public_html folder. and i edited my index.php file.
here is the code of my index.php file

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

?>
```

But still i am getting this error.anybody please help me

This page isn’t working
desktim.contents.management is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Check log file under /storage/logs/larave.log file. or paste error shown.

Answer (score 0):

**Revert your index.php file to its original state and use following method**

As Burak Erdem mentioned, another option (and more preferable) is to put this in the \App\Providers\AppServiceProvider register() method.

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
   public function register()
   {
    // ...

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code in your `index.php` file

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: @TouseefAwan Not appearing in your code, you are remove `..`  just replace this line then check

Comment: i did that...still same issue

Comment: @TouseefAwan Then there is no problem in your `index.php` code, can you show me the `.htaccess` file code